# Passing Multiple Variables Into an Argument in R Studio

Tags: r

I am pretty new to R Studio and I am trying to pass multiple inputs into a single function. I am attempting to create an MLB player game by game log so I can find their avg standard deviation fantasy points. I'm using a package that allows me to call single players at once. It is: `batter_game_logs_fg(playerid, year = 2020)` this returns data for every game the player has played this season. Given there are over 500 active players I'd like to find a way to automate the playerid input into the function from a dataset I have of every playerid. Is there any way to do this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please provide the package you're using

Comment: It is baseballr

Answer (score 0):

You can try 2 players to see if that works.

```
Players <- c(“player1”, “player2”)

batter_game_logs_fg(Players, year = 2020)
```

The  `Players` Variable is a vector, and your function might accept it since even tho it has a length of 2, it’s still an individual argument to the function.